# What can cause the error "The property 'ShouldLoop' was not found in type 'LoopingSelector'?

Tags: runtime-error, winrt-xaml, designer, win-universal-app

In Visual Studio 2015, sometimes this error is reported:

[image: screenshot of the error]

The designer itself looks like this:

[image: designer screenshot]

After recompilation, the error disappears, so it's not too bad.

**Additional information**

- PageContent is a user control, displaying a page header and a content area
- the project is using version 10.0.10240.0 of the Universal Windows Platform
- I never used or referenced a looping selector in the whole project
- Executing user code in the xaml designer is *enabled*

**Update**

Here is the source of the user control *PageContent.xaml*:

```
<local:UserControlBase
    x:Class="Prjm.Uwa.BasicControls.PageContent"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Prjm.Uwa.BasicControls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="100"
    d:DesignWidth="300"
    x:Name="PageContentControl">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" x:Name="mainGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <local:PageHeader x:Name="Header" Title="{x:Bind PageTitle}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <ProgressRing Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="80" Height="50" IsActive="False" Margin="10,10,10,10" x:Name="progressIndicator"/>
        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="{x:Bind MainContent}" Margin="8,0,0,0" Name="mainContent" />
    </Grid>

</local:UserControlBase>
```

The corresponding *PageContent.xaml.cs* file contains:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup;

namespace Prjm.Uwa.BasicControls {

    [ContentProperty(Name = "MainContent")]
    public sealed partial class PageContent : UserControlBase {

        public PageContent() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string PageTitle {
            get { return (string)GetValue(PageTitleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PageTitleProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty PageTitleProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("PageTitle", typeof(string), typeof(PageContent), new PropertyMetadata("Page title"));

        public object MainContent {
            get { return (object)GetValue(MainContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MainContentProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MainContentProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MainContent", typeof(object), typeof(PageContent), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public ProgressRing ProgressIndicator { get {
                return progressIndicator;
            }
        }

        public Visibility ContentVisibility {
            get {
                return mainContent.Visibility;
            }
            set {
                mainContent.Visibility = value;
            }
        }

    }    

}
```

I'm using this sample page class *ProjectPage.xaml*:

```
<local:EditProjectPage
    x:Class="Prjm.Uwa.Project.ProjectPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="using:Prjm.Uwa.Project"
    xmlns:ctrls="using:Prjm.Uwa.BasicControls"
    xmlns:env="using:Prjm.Uwa.Environment"    
    xmlns:main="using:Prjm.Uwa"            
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <ctrls:PageContent PageTitle="Edit Project">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <ctrls:LabelledTextInput 
                Label="Project name" 
                TextValue="{x:Bind ViewModel.Instance.Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />

            <Button Grid.Row="1"  Click="Button_Click">Test</Button>
        </Grid>
    </ctrls:PageContent>

</local:EditProjectPage>
```

The associated *ProjectPage.xaml.cs* contains:

```
using Prjm.Uwa.BasicControls;
using Prjm.Uwa.DataAccess;
using Prjm.ViewData.Project;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;

namespace Prjm.Uwa.Project {

    public class EditProjectPage : EditDataPage<ViewProject> {

        protected override ICreateReadUpdateDelete<ViewProject> CreateStorage() {
            return new ProjectStorage();
        }

    }

    public sealed partial class ProjectPage : EditProjectPage {

        public ProjectPage() : base() {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It'll be helpful if you could post the code that results in the error. At the moment your question is likely to be closed as it has no MCVE (Minimum Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: @bob: Added the source of the user control. Is the source for the page class required too?

Comment: Might as well, to get the best possible answer.

Comment: @bob: I have to admin that I've done some abstraction here: I didn't want to have code duplication, so I createad a lot of base- / utility classes, so the posted code might not be helpfull at all.

Comment: I think this is another case of a strange error message, which i can't decrypt because of missing experience. How can a xaml-file produce an error on a component, that I didn't ever use? Or is a looping selector part of the used components?

Comment: I want to encourage you by telling you that I got this same error when creating Template 10. I want to publicly shame myself by telling you that I did not document how I resolved it, but I did. I am 99% sure that commenting out the ContentPresenter would resolve it. Not helpful, I know.